# PM2 restart delay Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I'm using this code in my own app:

`pm2.restart('myapp', function() {});`

Works fine, but how can I include delayed restart to that?

`--restart-delay=3000`

Comment: Is your app named "myapp" in your ecosystem file?

Comment: I don't use ecosystem file. Is it possible to do without it?

Comment: Yes it is, as answered below you should define this configuration in the start function.

Comment: Why would someone want a delay? I am trying to understand the utility of this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [API docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/) you should define this configuration "restartDelay" in your Start function, the restart only stop and start it again:

```
  pm2.start({
    name         : 'myapp',   // Script name
    script       : 'app.js',  // Script to be run
    exec_mode    : 'cluster', // Allows your app to be clustered
    restartDelay : 3000,      // Number of ms to wait before restarting the script
  }, function(err, apps) {
    pm2.disconnect();   // Disconnects from PM2
    if (err) throw err
  });
```